# Awk input variable as a rule

Tags: awk

Good day!

I have the next code:

```
BLOCK=`awk '
/\/\* R \*\// {
  level=1
  count=0
}
level {
  n = split($0, c, "");
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    printf(c[i]);
    if (c[i] == ";")
    {
        if(level==1)
        {
            level = 0;
            if (count != 0)
                printf("\n");
        };
    }
    else if (c[i] == "{")
    {
        level++;
        count++;
    }
    else if (c[i] == "}")
    {
        level--;
        count++;
    }
  }
  printf("\n")
}' $i`
```

That code cuts the piece of the file from `/* R */` mark to the ';' symbol with taking into account the details like braces etc. But that isn't important. I want to replace the hard-coded /* R */ by the variable:

```
RECORDSEQ="/* R */"
...
BLOCK=`awk -v rec="$RECORDSEQ" '
rec {
  level=1
  count=0
}
```

But that doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe `$0 ~ rec{...}`

Comment: But it already uses $0 since it reads from file: `}  }  printf("\n")}' i`

Comment: Mark is right. To get dynamic regexes (a regex read from a string) to work you need to explicitly use the regex operator.

Comment: I'm sorry. I might be wrong in coding, but that doesn't work for me, I see empty output: `$0 ~ rec {  level=1  count=0 } ...`

Comment: Quoting in regexp constants is different than quoting in string constants. You might need to add some quoting. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps

Comment: You should not use old and outdated back-tics, use parentheses like this: `BLOCK=$(awk 'code....')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
RECORDSEQ="/* R */"

# Construct regexp for awk
RECORDSEQREG=`echo "$RECORDSEQ" | sed 's:\/:\\\/:g;s:\*:\\\*:g'`

# Cycle for files
for i in $SOURCE;
do
    # Find RECORDSEQ and cut out the block
    BLOCK=`awk -v rec="$RECORDSEQREG" '
$0 ~ rec {
  level=1
  count=0
}
...
```

Many thanks to people who helped.